# Java Scanner Delimiter without \n

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have a problem that's breaking my mind. I have a .txt file that looks like

```
fiat,regata,15*renault,seiscientos,25*
```

In my code I have this

```
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("coches.txt");
        sc.useDelimiter("[,*]");
        while(sc.hasNext()){   
            marca=new StringBuffer(sc.next());
            modelo=new StringBuffer(sc.next());
            marca.setLength(10);
            modelo.setLength(10);
            edad=sc.nextInt();

            coche=new Coche(marca.toString(),modelo.toString(),edad);
            coches.add(coche);
        }
```

The problem here is that the While loop is working three times, so the third time marca=\n and It stops with a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. So, How can I use my delimiter to stop de loop in the last * and avoid It to enter in that extra/problematic time?.

I already tried things like

```
while(sc.next!="\n")
```

I also triyed this and doesn't work

sc.useDelimiter("[,\*\n]");

SOLVED!!!

I finally found the solution, in part thanks to the advice of user1542723. The solution
 is:

```
String linea;
String [] registros,campos;    
File f=new File("coches.txt");
FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);//ALL this need Try Catch that I'm not posting

while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
        registros=linea.split("\\*");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
        campos=registros[i].split(",");
        marca=campos[0];
        modelo=campos[1];
        edad=Integer.parseInt(campos[2]);//that's an Int, edad means Age

        coche=new Coche(marca.toString(),modelo.toString(),edad);
        coches.add(coche);
    }
}
```

Thank you everybody who helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to escape the star in your regex:

`sc.useDelimiter("[,\\*]");`

Because

`"[,*]"` means `,` zero or more times and `"[,\\*]"` means  `,` or `*`.

Comment: Ok, I did that but I still have the same problem.

Comment: what if you add any whitespace? like `sc.useDelimiter("[,\\*\\s+]");` ?

Comment: why don't you read a complete line with the scanner, split it by `"\\*"` and split the result by `","`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.split("\\*")` to split first at the *, and then you have 1 array entry for each record, then use again `split(",")` to get al the values you now have.

**Example:**

```
String input = "fiat,regata,15*renault,seiscientos,25*";
String[] lines = input.split("\\*");
for(String subline : lines) {
    String[] data = subline.split(",");
    // Do something with data here
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subline));
}
```

Comment: Thank's mate, you gave me the clue.